# create force directed layout gexf file with node position generation

Tags: php, graph, directed-graph

In my Database i've got nodes and edges.

Position must have generated at gexf generation, the node must not overlap and

generate this kind of Graph:  http://www.nwoods.com/components/images/force-directed-layout.png

I use Sigma.js for presentating the graph.

*How can i calculate the node postition with an force directed alogrithm, with a root item?*

Or there a layout that can generate from node and edges a layout that not overlap and output like this png above?

EDIT:

PHP code for generating node position:

```
    function _generate_gexf_node($test=false){
        $count = 0;     
    foreach ($node_array as $node) {
        $node_size = '22.714287';
        $node_poz = ' x="'.rand(10, 300).'" y="'.rand(10, 300).'" z="'.rand(10, 300).'" ';
        $node_color = ' b="45" g="72" r="216" ';
        $data['node'][] = '<node id="'.$node['node_id'].'" label="'.$node['label'].'">
    <attvalues>
    <attvalue for="authority" value="0.01880342"/>
    <attvalue for="hub" value="0.01880342"/>
    </attvalues>
    <viz:size value="'.$node_size.'"/>
    <viz:color '.$node_color.'/>
    <viz:position '.$node_poz.'/>
    </node>
        ';
        $count++;
    }
            return $data;
      }
```

How can i gnerete the position in "runtime", to like this http://www.nwoods.com/components/images/force-directed-layout.png?

Where can i find implementation of YiFan Hu Force directed algorithm?

Or a special Bubble layout implementation?

Comment: Well you should actually at least show the php code and the according data (files?) you have so far for gexf file generation as there is no standard graph library with PHP out-of-the-box.

Comment: Gephi use YiFanHU multilevel algorithym.
I test is and it make the random layout very good.
http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/YifanHu_Multilevel
How can i use this with php? Or there are implementation?

Comment: I couldn't get the example in your question to run, code and data is missing.

Comment: You might be interested to learn about the meaning of SSCCE .- http://web.archive.org/web/20090224023444/http://sscce.org/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Answer (score 1):

at the moment i work also on a Web Graph Visualization but with javascript.
Here exists a good project called gexf-js (https://github.com/raphv/gexf-js)
but this is only for drawing the graph.

For the layout stuff i used the gephi library (this is implemented in java)
you can download it here https://gephi.org/toolkit/. And i found also a good example 
for the YifanHu layout Algorithm.

If it it could a manual task than you can import your gexf file in the gephi program
runt the layouter you want and export it as gexf. Most of all function in the gephi program
are also available in the toolkit library.

Hopefully this helps
nice day